# MediaTransportControls with Custom Button and Flyout

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

In my app I have a `MediaTransortControls` Template which I copied from the default System templates and removed a couple of in-needed buttons and added one `AppBarButton` with a `Flyout`. The flyout only hosts a `TextBlock` control to show some data. It shows the data fine if the `MediaPlayerElement` is in `non-full screen` state but there is no data shown in the flyout as soon as the `MediaPlayerElement`goes full screen.

I have no way to know that why is this causing an issue. The data gets updated in real time as normal when not in full screen but as long as you go full screen there is no data. When you come back you can see the data again.

Is this the normal behavior for the `MediaPlayerElement`?

Custom Template:

```
<Style TargetType="MediaTransportControls"
           x:Key="myCustomTransportControls">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="IsTextScaleFactorEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MediaTransportControls">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <!-- New AppBar button style 48x48 pixels in size -->
                            <Style x:Key="AppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{ThemeResource MTCMediaButtonWidth}" />
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{ThemeResource MTCMediaButtonHeight}" />
                                <Setter Property="AllowFocusOnInteraction" Value="True" />
                            </Style>
                            <!-- New CommandBar Style -->
                            <Style x:Key="CommandBarStyle" TargetType="CommandBar">
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{ThemeResource MTCMediaButtonHeight}" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                            </Style>
                            <!-- Style for Error Message text -->
                            <Style x:Key="MediaTextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource MTCMediaFontSize}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource MTCMediaFontFamily}" />
                                <Setter Property="Style" Value="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle }" />
                                <Setter Property="IsTextScaleFactorEnabled" Value="False" />
                            </Style>
                            <!-- Style for Position slider used in Media Transport Controls -->
                            <Style x:Key="MediaSliderStyle" TargetType="Slider">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackFill}" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackValueFill}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
                                <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None" />
                                <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
                                <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-7,0,-7,0" />
                                <Setter Property="IsFocusEngagementEnabled" Value="True" />
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                                            <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                                <Grid.Resources>
                                                    <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyle">
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SliderThumbBackground}" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumBrush}" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse"
                                                                    Stroke="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                                    StrokeThickness="2"
                                                                    Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                                            </Setter.Value>
                                                        </Setter>
                                                    </Style>
                                                    <Style TargetType="ProgressBar" x:Key="MediaSliderProgressBarStyle">
                                                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{ThemeResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Minimum" Value="0" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Maximum" Value="100" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightChromeAltLowBrush}" />
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                                                    </Style>
                                                </Grid.Resources>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Border x:Name="ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border">
                            <Grid x:Name="ControlPanelGrid"
                            Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="TranslateVertical"/>
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Border x:Name="ErrorBorder"
                                        Width="320"
                                        Height="96"
                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlPageBackgroundAltMediumBrush}"
                                        Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="ErrorTextBlock"
                                               Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
                                               TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"
                                               Margin="12" />
                                </Border>
                                <Border x:Name="MediaTransportControls_Timeline_Border" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                                    <Grid x:Name="MediaTransportControls_Timeline_Grid">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Slider x:Name="ProgressSlider"
                                        Style="{StaticResource MediaSliderStyle}"
                                        Margin="12,0"
                                        MinWidth="80"
                                        Height="33"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        IsThumbToolTipEnabled="False" />
                                        <ProgressBar x:Name="BufferingProgressBar"
                                        Height="4"
                                        IsIndeterminate="True"
                                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        Margin="0,2,0,0"
                                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                        <Grid x:Name="TimeTextGrid"
                                        Margin="12,0"
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Height="15">
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="TimeElapsedElement"
                                            Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
                                            Margin="0"
                                            Text="00:00"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="TimeRemainingElement"
                                            Style="{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}"
                                            Text="00:00"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                                <Border x:Name="LeftSidePlayBorder"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Visibility="Collapsed">
                                    <AppBarButton x:Name="PlayPauseButtonOnLeft"
                                    Margin="0"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
                                        <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            <SymbolIcon x:Name="PlayPauseSymbolLeft" Symbol="Play" />
                                        </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                    </AppBarButton>
                                </Border>
                                <Border x:Name="MediaTransportControls_Command_Border"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.Row="2">
                                    <CommandBar x:Name="MediaControlsCommandBar" 
                                                Margin="0,0"
                                                Style="{StaticResource CommandBarStyle}" 
                                                IsDynamicOverflowEnabled="False">
                                        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='VolumeMuteButton'
                                            Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                            MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='919'>
                                                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                                                    <Flyout x:Name='VolumeFlyout' FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource FlyoutStyle}">
                                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='AudioMuteButton'
                                                                Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                                                VerticalAlignment='Center'
                                                                HorizontalAlignment='Center'
                                                                Margin='12'>
                                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                                    <SymbolIcon x:Name='AudioMuteSymbol' Symbol='Volume' />
                                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                            </AppBarButton>
                                                            <Slider x:Name='VolumeSlider'
                                                                  Value='50'
                                                                  IsThumbToolTipEnabled='False'
                                                                  Width='{ThemeResource MTCHorizontalVolumeSliderWidth}'
                                                                  VerticalAlignment='Center'
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment='Center'
                                                                  Margin='0'/>
                                                            <TextBlock x:Name='VolumeValue'
                                                                    Style='{StaticResource MediaTextBlockStyle}'
                                                                    Text="{Binding ElementName=VolumeSlider,Path=Value}"
                                                                    HorizontalAlignment='Center'
                                                                    VerticalAlignment='Center'
                                                                    Width='24'
                                                                    Margin='12'/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </Flyout>
                                                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <SymbolIcon x:Name='VolumeMuteSymbol' Symbol='Volume' />
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            </AppBarButton>


                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='CCSelectionButton'
                                          Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                          MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='15'
                                          Visibility='Collapsed'>
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xED1E;"/>
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            </AppBarButton>

                                            <AppBarButton x:Name="MediaInfoButton"
                                                          Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE783;"/>
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                <AppBarButton.Flyout>
                                                    <Flyout FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource FlyoutStyle}">
                                                        <TextBlock Name="IBlock"
                                                                   Text="{Binding Path=VideoInfoText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                                   Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Flyout>
                                                </AppBarButton.Flyout>
                                            </AppBarButton>
    <!-- This is the custom button "MediaInfoButton" which I added -->

                                            <AppBarSeparator/>

                                                                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='PlayPauseButton'
                                            Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                            MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='23'>
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <SymbolIcon x:Name='PlayPauseSymbol' Symbol='Play' />
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            </AppBarButton>

                                            <AppBarSeparator/>

                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='ZoomButton'
                                            Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                            MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='9'>
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE799;"/>
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            </AppBarButton>
                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='CastButton'
                                            Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                            MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='11'>
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEC15;"/>
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            </AppBarButton>
                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='FullWindowButton'
                                            Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                            MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='20'>
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <SymbolIcon x:Name='FullWindowSymbol' Symbol='FullScreen' />
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            </AppBarButton>

                                            <!--
                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='FastForwardButton'
                                          Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                          MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='1'
                                          Visibility='Collapsed'>
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEB9D;"/>
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            </AppBarButton>
                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='NextTrackButton'
                                            Icon='Next'
                                            Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                            MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='3'
                                            Visibility='Collapsed'/>
                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='SkipForwardButton'
                                            Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                            MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='5'
                                            Visibility='Collapsed'>
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xED3D;"/>
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            </AppBarButton>
                                            <AppBarButton x:Name='PlaybackRateButton'
                                            Style='{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}'
                                            MediaTransportControlsHelper.DropoutOrder='10'
                                            Visibility='Collapsed'>
                                                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                                                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xEC57;"/>
                                                </AppBarButton.Icon>
                                            </AppBarButton>
                                            -->
                                            <!--
                                            <AppBarSeparator x:Name='RightSeparator'
                                            Height='0'
                                            Width ='0'
                                            Margin='0,0' />
                                            -->

                                        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>

                                        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>

                                        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
                                    </CommandBar>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Note: I cant put the whole Template it's too big for the question body.

Images:

[image: Flyout behavour in Non-FullScreen]
[image: Flyout behavior in FullScreen]

Can someone point out what I can do to make this work also in the full-screen?
Or maybe to hide the button altogether when the player is in full-screen?
Thanks

**Update:**

This is the Binding Property in code-behind:

```
    private string mediaInfo;
    public string VideoInfoText
    {
        get
        {
            if (mediaInfo == null || mediaInfo == "")
                return "Information will be shown when the video starts playing.";
            return mediaInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != mediaInfo)
            {
                mediaInfo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the method that actually updates the data:

```
private async void MediaView_DownloadProgressChanged(MediaPlaybackSession sender, object args)
    {
        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var i = MediaView.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.DownloadProgress;
                string p = sender.IsProtected ? "Protection enabled." : "Protection not available.";
                HtmlDocs.INotifyObject.VideoInfoText = $"DRM: {p}\nVideo Height: {sender.NaturalVideoHeight}\nVideo Width: {sender.NaturalVideoWidth}" +
                $"\n{string.Format("Video Stream Progress: {0:0.00}%", (i * 100))}";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: I test the `Flyout` that can be shown in the full-screen. Do you mean you can not get the text by binding in the full-screen? If not, could you share a [MCVE] that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: The text displayed in the 1st pic is actually from the `Binding` property as displayed in the style above. It displays the text in the non-full screen but doesn't display the text in full screen as indicated in the pics. And yes, it doesn't show the text from the binding in full screen but it displays the static data if it is put in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by setting the `DataContext` of the Custom class to the `Binding` object and it started showing the text in the full-screen. First the `DataContext` was only set in the main page that hosted the media player and it worked fine for non-full screen but in the full screen it only worked after setting the `DataContext` above.